# How do I format this data?

Tags: excel, text, formatting

My text file currently has data in this format:

```
------------NEW CALCULATION-----------
1.09532773E-02  9.93E-02
3.76554509E-03  9.93E-02
7.53080333E-03  9.93E-02
1.12954900E-02  9.93E-02
1.50593193E-02  9.92E-02
1.88220125E-02  9.92E-02
2.25832891E-02  9.92E-02
------------NEW CALCULATION-----------
9.71343145E-02  9.84E-02
0.100812949 9.84E-02
0.104485862 9.83E-02
0.108152986 9.83E-02
0.111814260 9.82E-02
```

So the beginning of each new calculation there is a little "----NEW CALCULATION----" message, and then the numbers go in two columns. 
Currently, I use excel to get all the numbers into two columns, but I can't find a way to separate each calculation in its own set of columns. For example, I would want the data above to look like (separated into four columns):

```
1.09532773E-02  9.93E-02  9.71343145E-02    9.84E-02
3.76554509E-03  9.93E-02  0.100812949   9.84E-02
7.53080333E-03  9.93E-02  0.104485862   9.83E-02
1.12954900E-02  9.93E-02  0.108152986   9.83E-02
1.50593193E-02  9.92E-02  0.111814260   9.82E-02
1.88220125E-02  9.92E-02
2.25832891E-02  9.92E-02
```

Notice that the two columns do not have the same number of data points.

Someone please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptionally quick and dirty python script:

```py
import itertools

so = "\t" # separator for output
infile = "infile" # file input
outfile = "outfile" # file output

s = open(infile).read()
sep = "------------NEW CALCULATION-----------\n"
s = [i.strip().split('\n') for i in s.strip(sep).split(sep)]
s = [[j.strip().split() for j in i] for i in s]
s = list(map(list,list(itertools.zip_longest(*s,fillvalue=['\t\t\t']))))
o = open("outfile","w")
for i in [so.join([i for j in s2 for i in j]) for s2 in s]:
    o.write(i+"\n")
```

Comment: Where in the OP's question was the Python platform mentioned?